# How to get a pointer to a specific section of a dynamic library (Linux ELF)?

Tags: c, linux, memory, elf, dynamic-library

As can be seen in the [second answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159595/how-to-get-a-pointer-to-an-specific-section-of-a-program-from-within-itself-ma) , it's quite simple to get a pointer to an specific section of a program from within itself, using the section's name. With `libelf`, just open the program's own file, loop over all sections (which are represented by `Elf64_Shdr` structs) in it, stop when the section name matches the one you want and use the pointer stored in the `sh_addr` element of the `Elf64_Shdr` struct. In this case, it's very simple to get the wanted pointer because it is defined in the ELF executable file.

But, imagine you have a program that uses a dynamic library and you need to get a pointer to a section of that dynamic library. Since the addresses of its sections are defined in runtime, how is it possible to get pointers to sections of a dynamic library?

By the way, both the dynamic library and the main program itself have, each one, a section with the same name (which is the one I need to get a pointer to). So, in this case, is it possible that these two sections with the same name are stored adjacently in memory, so that I just need to get a pointer to the main file's section (as I explained in the first paragraph) and add an offset to reach the dynamic library section?

Comment: You can get the start address from /proc/<pid>/maps, then you can just add the offset.

Comment: @Nick Ok, but what value to use for offset? Isn't there a more elegant way to do that, considering I can get the start address with `libelf`?

Comment: I'm not even sure whether two sections with the same name, one of the main file and the other of the library, are stored adjacently (they're most certainly not). So I don't even know whether using an offset is going to work...

Comment: Why are you asking? Sometimes, using `dladdr` could be enough....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's quite simple to get a pointer to an specific section of a program from within itself

Not necessarily. The section table is not actually needed at runtime, and can be completely stripped (only segments matter, not sections).

> Since the addresses of its sections are defined in runtime, how is it possible to get pointers to sections of a dynamic library?

The library is not at all different from the main executable. The main difference is that the library is usually linked at address `0` (the main executable is not), and *relocated* by the runtime loader to some other constant offset.

Once you know that offset, just add it to the section start (which you can find from `readelf -S foo.so` or from libelf), and voila: you've got the runtime address of the section.

So how can you find the relocation for a given shared library?

Inelegant solution (already suggested by Nick) is to parse `/proc/self/maps`.

A better solution is to use (glibc-specific) `dl_iterate_phdr`. Documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr). You'll want to use `dlpi_addr` .

Comment: That's great, man! Thank you very much for talking about `dl_iterate_phdr`. I'll try to use it, since it seems to be exactly what I need. But, talking about your first observation ("the section table can be completely stripped"), so you mean the `sh_addr` element of a `Elf64_Shdr` structure is not always garanteed to be a pointer that can be used to reach a section, for a main file?

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite The entire `.shstrtab` section can be stripped. Without it, you can't know what the names of the sections are  (or rather, used to be).

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, herein an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = 2;
int j __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = 3;
int k __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = 5;

extern int __start_my_section;
extern int __stop_my_section;

int main(void)
{
    int *p = &__start_my_section;

    printf("%d\n", *p++); /* print k value */
    printf("%d\n", *p++); /* print j value */
    printf("%d\n", *p);   /* print i value */

   return 0;
}
```